# If C and D are closed and C is bounded, then C+D is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $C,D\subset R^n$ are both closed. And C is bounded.
Prove $C+D $ is closed.

I am having a hard time understanding why C being bounded matters.
Also, I have no idea how to start.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You may try using the sequencial criterion to prove that $C+D$ is closed : take a converging sequence in $C+D$ and prove that the limit stays in $C+D$. You will need to use boundedness of $C$ somewhere.

Comment: First consider examples where $C+D$ is not closed for $C,D$ closed. There are plenty on this site alone.

Comment: The important property of C is that it is compact.

Comment: One amusing example with $n=1$ where $C,D$ are both closed and unbounded: Let $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1)=\{q_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ and let $C=\{n+q_n: n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Let $D=\Bbb Z.$ Then $C+D=\Bbb Q.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Cauchy sequence $ \{ x_n \} $ in $ C + D $.  Our goal is to show that its limit is in $ C + D $.  By definition, $ x_n = c_n + d_n $.  Now by the boundedness of $ C $... do you see what you can accomplish?  If you still need help, I'll finish this in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

In a closed and bounded set any sequence has a convergent subsequence. Suppose $x_n=c_n+d_n \to z$ with $c_n \in C$ and $d_n \in D$ for all $n$. There exists $(n_k)$ such that $c_{n_k} \to$ some point $x \in C$. Since $c_{n_k}+d_{n_k} \to z$ we see that $d_{n_k} \to z-x$. Since $D$ is closed, $z-x \in D$. Hence $z =x+(z-x) \in C+D$.

I have used Bolzano -Weierstrass Theorem in the proof. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: Thank you. However, where do we need Boundedness?

Comment: If $C$ is not bounded the the subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ may not exist. [ For example $C$ could be $\{1,2,3,...\}$]. @measurehell

Comment: Also, if $c_{2n}=1=d_{2k+1}$ and $c_{2n+1}=-1=d_{2n}$, we get $x_n=0$. However, $c_n $ and $d_n$ do not converge. How do we cover this kind of special case?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you please explain why boundedness is related to the subsequence? or would you please let me know some internet link that will help me understand it?

Comment: You do to the subsequences $(c_{2n})$ and $(d_{2n})$ in this case, To prove that $C+D$ is closed you need not use the entire sequence $(c_n)$ and $(d_2)$.

Comment: @measurehell See my revised answer .